# Implementing Live Search using Jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am a newbie in this field.

I have a sharepoint list containing a set of data and as the user enters his input in the text box it should display the options.

Planning to implement in keyup but unable to understand how to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `jquery-ui` plugin which includes the `autocomplete` module.

Demo & Documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: +1 no need to reinvent the wheel. You can also learn a lot if you read and understand the source code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI propose a widget for autocompletion at this page http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/.
It's possible to have remote datasource. You may find your happyness.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

- [Search as you type in SharePoint](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/07/automatically-add-search-as-you-type-to.html)
- [Real time filtering in SharePoint Lists](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/09/add-real-time-filtering-to-all-lists.html)

Comment: This is a good example of a "link-only" answer that should be expanded to include: 1) the name of the tool you are recommending, 2) that you wrote the tool, and 3) a simple example of its use.  Merely linking to an external blog entry is not sufficient.